# SVN working copy of trunk and commit to branch

Tags: svn, subclipse

I am new to svn and am struggling with some basics.

I am using Subclipse for all the below. I have checked out a copy of the trunk as my local working copy. I have created a branch from my "local working copy of trunk".

- I want to commit changes from local working copy of trunk to the new branch I created. But when I click commit, it will commit to trunk and not the new branch. How do I commit to the new branch created?
- After that once I am fine with the branch, I want to merge the branch into the trunk.
  How do I merge the branch into the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

After you create the branch, you need to "switch" your working copy to that branch.  There is a checkbox on the Create branch dialog to do this, but you can also do it after the fact using Team > Switch.

To merge back to trunk, you must first switch your working copy to trunk.  Then use Team > Merge and choose your branch as the merge source.